# Minor's naturalisation reconsideration taking too long

Tags: visa-refusals, dual-nationality

We applied for reconsideration of a naturalisation refusal for our 4-year-old daughter in July 2016 and have still not heard any response from the nationality team.

Does any one know how long it takes to get a response of reconsideration results from the Home Office?

Both parents are British through naturalisation. Our daughter was on a family of a settled person visa for three years. The refusal stated she was not old enough. We challenged stating, as both parents are now British and daughter stayed in UK for more than three years, please consider our case.

Now our main concern is how long will they take to respond on that reconsideration, as her current visa expired we are stuck without travelling anywhere. Tried out of six months standard period but no response.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54114/discussion-on-question-by-sheyu-minors-naturalisation-reconsideration-taking-t).